# How would I Recursively get unique items out of nested lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, nested, nested-lists

So, I am a complete beginner to recursion.

I have to answer a question in which I define a function that takes nested lists consisting of numbers or letters as parameters and I have to return a dictionary containing all the unique values. (I have to solve this problem recursivley)

```
def extract_unique_elements(lists):
    if isinstance(lists, int):
        return {lists}

    for i in set(lists):
        return extract_unique_elements({i})
```

So obviously that isn't even close to working. If it were; however, when passed a nested list it would return as follows:

```
>>> extract_unique_elements([1,[2,1,[5,5,[2]]]]) 
{1,2,5}

>>> extract_unique_elements([a,[a,b,[c,b,[e]]]])
{a,b,c,e}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one way you can do it:

```
result = set()
lists = [1,[2,1,[5,5,[2]]]]

def extract_unique_elements(lists, result):
    if isinstance(lists, list):
        for item in lists:
            extract_unique_elements(item, result)

    else:
        result.add(lists)

extract_unique_elements(lists, result)

result
# {1, 2, 5}
```

Comment: The function may only take one parameter consisting of nested lists and must handle alphabets as well

Comment: It's not too hard to adapt this code to create a new `result` set at the start of the recursive chain. Just give it a sentinel default value like `None` and check for that at the start. It is a little more efficient to use just one set that you pass through the recursive calls than it is to build a separate results set on each level and need to copy data from the recursive results into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
def extract_unique_elements(lists):
    if isinstance(lists, int):
        return {lists}

    values = set()
    for i in lists:
        values.update(extract_unique_elements(i))

    return values
```

or:

```
def extract_unique_elements(lists):
    if isinstance(lists, int):
        return {lists}

    return {i for e in lists for i in extract_unique_elements(e)}
```

testing:

```
extract_unique_elements([1,[2,1,[5,5,[2]]]])
# {1, 2, 5}
```

if you want a more compact version you can use:

```
def extract_unique_elements(lists):
    return {i for e in lists  for i in ([e] if isinstance(e, int) else extract_unique_elements(e))}
```

Comment: A more efficient way of writing your first code would be to use `|=` rather than creating a new set on every iteration. You could also call the `update` method, which might be clearer than using an operator.

Comment: This works amazing for numbers but the only issue would be it will not handle letters.

Comment: @ThatGuy can you give an example

Comment: @ThatGuy you mean `extract_unique_elements(['a',['a','b',['c','b',['e']]]])`

Comment: @ThatGuy the return looks as expected, right? or I miss something?

Comment: for what data? what list of lists?

Comment: When I try and 'print' the variable values it gives me an error saying:     values.update(extract_unique_elements(i))
builtins.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: well, you wan to change the function?

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
def myflatten(l):
    if type(l) != list:
        return([l])
    elif type(l) == list:
        if len(l) == 1:
            return(myflatten(l[0]))
        else:
            res = myflatten(l[0]) + myflatten(l[1:])
            return(res)

print(set(myflatten([1,[2,1,[5,5,[2]]]])))
#{1, 2, 5}

# OR (rectified):

def myflatten(l):
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return [l]
    else:
        if len(l) == 1:
            return myflatten(l[0])
        else:
            res = myflatten(l[0]) + myflatten(l[1:])
            return res
```

Comment: There are a number of unpythonic things in this code: `isinstance(SomeType, some_object)` is preferred over `type(some_object) == SomeType` because the former respects subclasses. `return` is not a function, you don't need parentheses around the value you're returning. You don't need to test both a condition and its inverse in an `if` and `elif`. If the `if` is hit, you'll never test the `elif` condition, and if its false the `elif` condition will always be true. So just use `else`. Or, since you're returning from the `if`, you could unconditionally run the code currently in the `else` blocks.